# If $V$ is a $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $R^n$, then $V$ is the kernel of a linear transformation $T : R^n → R^{n−k}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, dimensional-analysis

If $V$ is a $k$-dimensional linear subspace of $R^n$, then $V$ is the kernel of a linear transformation $T : R^n → R^{n−k}.$

Basically just looking for whether this is True or False.

Comment: Yes, it's true. You can write down such a linear transformation by picking a basis of $V$ and extending it to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the *quotient map* onto $\Bbb R^n/V\cong\Bbb R^{n-k}$.  (Halmos is a good reference on this.)